# c# run .msu install from code

Tags: c#, silent-installer

Is there a way to run silently .msu installation from code?

I know it's possible with msi files, but when I run .msu, it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends on what you mean by "from code".  If you are willing to run a separate EXE (rather than invoke an API), then you can use `WUSA.exe` to install .MSU files. See KB 934307, 
[Description of the Windows Update Stand-alone Installer (Wusa.exe) and of.msu files in Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 and in Windows Server 2008 R2](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307).

> `/quiet`: Run Wusa.exe in quiet mode without user interaction. When the
>   tool runs in quiet mode, it runs without user interaction. The
>   computer restarts if it is required. [ . . . ]
>
> `/norestart`: Prevent Wusa.exe from restarting the computer. The
>   /norestart switch is ignored if the /quiet switch is not present. [ .
>   . . ]
>
> For example, if the Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu file is in the
>   D:\934307 folder, type the following command at a command prompt to
>   install the update package: `wusa.exe
>   D:\934307\Windows6.0-KB934307-x86.msu /quiet /norestart`